# Finding an array item in state

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have the following array in my Sate:

```
this.state = {
currentAsset: null,    
assets: [
    { id: uuidv4(), selected: false, text: 'Sorte',},
    { id: uuidv4(), selected: false, text: 'optical_dillusion2322.jpg'},
    { id: uuidv4(), selected: false, text: 'man_read_abook3242332.jpg'},
```

]
}

I want to find one of these assets and assign it to `currentAsset`.  I have the following function:

```
handleAssetIDChange(assetID) {
    console.log(assetID)
    var currentAsset = this.state['assets'][assetID]
    console.log(currentAsset)
    // this.setState({
    //     currentAsset: this.state['assets'][assetID],
    //     openAssetSideBar: true
    // }, () => {
    //     console.log(this.state['assets'][assetID])
    // })
}
```

You can see the commented out part is now working.  I am trying to set the `currentAsset` and then trigger the open of the sidebar to display the contents, but `currentAsset` is not getting set.

I have the assetID, how can I locate the one I need?  Another question i have is in many stackoverflow posts they reference state vars like objects, aka:

`this.state.assets` but I always get an error when trying to do that.

How can I assign `currentAsset` and then trigger the openAssetSidebar when it has been set?

Comment: What error do you always get when accessing `this.state.assets`? There’s not much information here to go on.

Comment: I could see in this,state that you haven't closed your array properly.

Comment: @DaveNewton PHPStorm says unrecognized variable assets and React doesnt throw an error but still doesnt assign currentAsset when I run this line: `var currentAsset = this.state.assets[assetID]`

Comment: @rishabhtripathi Sorry its just a snippet, the array is much longer I trimmed it down.  It is closed in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a filter use get the object, this should update your currentAsset in the state.

```
handleAssetIDChange(assetID) {
    console.log(assetID)
    var currentAsset = this.state['assets'].filter( item => item.id === assetID)[0]
    console.log(currentAsset)
     this.setState(( prev ) => {
         ...prev,
         currentAsset,
         openAssetSideBar: true
     })
}
```

Comment: That works! Thanks! Any idea as to my other question, why I can't access state vars as `this.state.assets` ??

Comment: AH weird did you update the question didn't even notice the other questions. Let me update the answer

Comment: We might need more code to determine why you cant access this.state.assets. Can you show entire component?

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the asset that you are looking for with a specific id, instead of

```
var currentAsset = this.state['assets'][assetID]
```

You should do:

```
const foundAsset = this.state['assets'].find((el) => el.id === assetID)
```

then to update the state, you would do:

```
this.setState((prev) => ({...prev, currentAsset: foundAsset}))
```